# Bypass the Origin header check and CSRF attack

Tags: security, web, xss, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm trying to do some csrf attack test on a site.
I found that the site protect itself from csrf by checking the http `Origin` header.

But I guess maybe under some conditions I can bypass the protection. When I delete the `Origin` header, the csrf attack success.
It means that the server only check the Origin heaer for csrf protection and accept an `"none"` value.

Any way to do the following exploit please?